# glob with if statement to select which files to store to a variable?

Tags: python, for-loop, glob

I have this code that checks from the directory what files to store for later processing:

```
for i in glob(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol' + '**/*/*/*', recursive=True):
    if i.endswith('PAD.shp'):
        print(i)
        pad = gpd.read_file(i)
    if i.endswith('DND.shp'):
        print(i)
        dnd = gpd.read_file(i)
```

only stores the `dnd`. Although there is the rest and it doesn't store it.

To give you an idea what's going on check this where it prints what it finds:

```
for i in glob(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol' + '**/*/*/*', recursive=True):
    if i.endswith('PAD.shp'):
        print('PAD:'+i)
    elif i.endswith('DND.shp'):
        print('DND:'+i)
```

which gives:

```
DND:C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol\43001\DND\DND.shp
PAD:C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol\43001\PAD\PAD.shp
DND:C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol\43003\DND\DND.shp
PAD:C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol\43003\PAD\PAD.shp
```

How to get both files `dnd` and `pad` in each iteration from each folder?

**What I think could be wrong:**

It searches the directory, and since it first stores the `dnd` (as it can be seen in the last piece of code where it prints everything) it proceeds without having check the rest of the directory. Thus the `pad` isn't assigned with anything.

**Solution**

A solution can be to force the iteration to assign each `dnd` and `pad` from the same folder (for example folder `43001`) and then procceed to the calculations and when finished then take the next folder with the correct pairs again.

How this can be done?

Comment: what do you mean by "only stores the dnd. Although there is the rest it doesn't store it." ... that pad files are not stored or that it only stores 1 dnd file and that's all?

Comment: I mean that it stores the DND.shp in dnd and not the PAD.shp in the pad

Comment: So in your first loop case, what happens exactly for the variable pad after the loop. Is there an error and if not is the variable defined after the loop and if it is (I imagine that's what you meant), what does it contain? None, '' ? etc...

Comment: for the pad it says the variable pad is not defined.So nothing is assign to that variable.

Comment: Check the question with an update I made

Comment: Maybe try the code underneath just to test what is actually stored... what's weird is that everything is printed fine in your second loop right? if the first loop your whole code or is there some additional code that could cause the loop to break?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what can be happening in your code but maybe try the following code to help debugging

```
pads = {}
dnds = {}
for i in glob(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol' + '**/*/*/*', recursive=True):
    if i.endswith('PAD.shp'):
        print("file:", i)
        pads[i] = gpd.read_file(i)
        print("len:", len(pads[i]))
    elif i.endswith('DND.shp'):
        print("file:", i)
        dnds[i] = gpd.read_file(i)
        print("len:", len(dnds[i]))
print("loaded pads:", pads.keys())
print("loaded dnds:", dnds.keys())
```

Just to follow what's happening more closely and see what exactly is loaded / if there is any error

Comment: in this code it stores only the pad files. As far as the rest of the code you said it isn't anything that may cause an issue because this is the assigning part.

Comment: I'm not so sure about what could be happening either... can you paste what is printed exactly in a comment?  maybe that will help understanding why it skips certain things @user10202223

Comment: it says:`NameError: name 'dnd' is not defined
`

Comment: Oh I meant the text printed by the code I gave above @user10202223 (I have no `dnd`var)

Comment: `loaded pads: dict_keys(['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\fol\\43001\\PAD\\PAD.shp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\fol\\43003\\PAD\\PAD.shp'])
loaded dnds: dict_keys([])`

Comment: Mmmmmh and what about the print lines with "file:" and "len:" ? What I don't get is how your second loop does print the 4 files and this should not... @user10202223

Comment: `file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol\43001\PAD\PAD.shp
len: 5266
file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\fol\43003\PAD\PAD.shp
len: 1657`